# Data operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a stored procedure who take a reference date, and add a hour to this element.

Here is my line doing the operation :

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @conductor_date), [HOUR])
```

For example, whith `@conductor_date = '2015-10-15'` and `[HOUR] = 23:00` it works and generate me a date like that : `'2015-10-15:23:00:00'`

I face a logical issue when the value [HOUR] is more than 24. In fact, to solve my problem I need to generate `'2015-10-16:00:40:00'` when `[HOUR] = 24:40`

Actualy with this values, I face the logical following exception :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

To sum up, I need to take care of hours that are more than '23:59' and switch to the next day :

```
DECLARE    @conductor_date datetime
DECLARE    @hour varchar(5)
SET @conductor_date = '2015-10-15'
SET @hour = '24:40'

SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @conductor_date), @hour)
```

Expected : `2015-10-16:00:40:00`

Comment: select dateadd(HOUR, 23, getdate()) as time_added, 
       getdate() as curr_date

Comment: Can you edit my example with your informations ?

Comment: is the type of hour fixed at `varchar(5)`?

Comment: Yes, `HH:mm` all time

Comment: Seems like a simple matter of programming.   What have you tried?   What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your `@hour` field into hours and minutes and add them separately:

```
DECLARE    @conductor_date datetime 
DECLARE    @hour varchar(5) 

DECLARE @hours int
DECLARE @minutes int
DECLARE @offset datetime

SET @conductor_date = '2015-10-15' 
SET @hour = '24:40'

SET @hours = cast(left(@hour, 2) as int)
SET @minutes = cast(right(@hour, 2) as int)
SET @offset = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0,@conductor_date), 0) -- the begin of the day

SELECT DATEADD(hour, @hours, dateadd(minute, @minutes, @offset))
```

Of course all can be done in one line but for sake of visualization I have put it into separate statements.

Comment: no need to add offset by giving conductor_date  in statement works fine . Extra line of code @flo

Comment: @Jonathan It depends on what the OP wants to achieve. In the original approach `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @conductor_date), @hour)` would have ignored time-fields of `@conductor_date`. My example works that way always. If `@conductor_date` has time fields and I don't truncate to the beginning of the day, the time fields would be added also.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx), date / time types don't support times larger then 23:59:59.9999999. You have to do manual string parsing for this.

First you need to extract the total hours, divide that by 24 to get total days. Then calculate leftover hours, and with that reconstruct your time offset.

With these in hand, you can build your required output value:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(20) = '24:40'
DECLARE @start VARCHAR(20) = '2015-10-15'

DECLARE @days INT
DECLARE @leftover INT

SET @leftover = CAST(LEFT(@v, 2) AS INT)
SET @days = @leftover / 24
SET @leftover = @leftover - @days * 24

SET @v = CAST(@leftover AS VARCHAR(2)) + SUBSTRING(@v, 3, 20)

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @days + DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @start), @v)
```

Here's a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5944).

This supports time string that start with HH (leading zeros) with any valid accuracy (HH:mm:ss.fffffff).

Comment: P.S. SQLFiddle is (typically) not working for me right now, so I can't validate this answer - there might be a typo or an error here and there. I'll try to add a link later.

Comment: There is a little error, i get `2015/10/16 00:00` but I expect : `2015/10/16 00:40`

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,(LEFT(@hour,2)*60+RIGHT(@hour,2)),@conductor_date)
```